# Blazor server Change top-row in MainLayout.razor

Tags: html, css, parameters, blazor-server-side

Blazor Server and .Net 6

In the Counter.razor page i add a button, this button call a method ChangeColor(), with this method i will like to change the color of the top-row div in the MainLayout.razor.

**Counter.razor**

```
@page "/counter"

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ChangeColor">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void ChangeColor()
    {
        *from_here_i_will_like_to_change_TOP_ROW_DIV*
    }
}
```

**MainLayout.razor**
@TopRowColor

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<PageTitle>BlazorApp1</PageTitle>

<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4" style="background-color: @TopRowColor">
            <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string TopRowColor { get; set; } = "red";  
  
}
```

My question is, how can I change the color of the upper bar from the Counter page

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. First, you'll create a service that holds the shared state

   ```
   public class TopRowStateService
    {
        public string TopRowColor
        {
            get;
            private set;
        } = "red"; // default color

        public event Action OnChange;

        public void SetTopRowColor(string color)
        {
            TopRowColor = color;
            NotifyStateChanged();
        }

        private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
    }
   ```
2. Register this service in Startup.cs or Program.cs (depending on your Blazor Server version) so that it can be injected into components:

   `builder.Services.AddScoped();`
3. Inject the TopRowStateService in MainLayout.razor and use its property for the div’s style:

`@inject TopRowStateService TopRowState

<div class="top-row px-4" style="background-color: @TopRowState.TopRowColor">
</div>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        TopRowState.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        TopRowState.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;
    }
}`

4. Inject the service in Counter.razor and use it to change the color:

`@inject TopRowStateService TopRowState
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ChangeColor">Click me</button>
    @code {

    private void ChangeColor()
    {
        TopRowState.SetTopRowColor("newColor"); 
    }
}`

Comment: Hi @SuryatejaKONDLA, could use some assistance on this. Here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77787179/11780009. Thanks!