# Blazor Server: Fetch Access Token from ProtectedStorage and Inject into HTTP Request Pipeline

Tags: .net-core, c#-4.0, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I am encountering difficulties in integrating a JWT token, retrieved from ProtectedSessionStorage in a Blazor Server project (.NET 8), into the HTTP request pipeline for authorization. I've provided relevant code snippets below:

`PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider`

```
public async override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
{
   TokenProvider tokenProvider = await GetTokenProvide();

   if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tokenProvider.AccessToken))
   {
      return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
   }

   AuthenticationState? state = new(new ClaimsPrincipal(new 
   ClaimsIdentity(GetClaimsFromJwt(tokenProvider.AccessToken), "jwt")));
   AuthenticationStateUser = state.User;

   return state;
}
```

I am using refit for my http calls I tried calling the `ProtectedSessionstorage` on each request with refit settings

```
public RefitService(IHttpClientFactory http, ProtectedSessionStorage sessionStorage)
{
    _client = http.CreateClient(HTTP_CLIENT_KEY);
    _sessionStorage = sessionStorage;

    _refitSettings = new(new NewtonsoftJsonContentSerializer())
    {
       AuthorizationHeaderValueGetter =  (request, cancellationToken) =>
       {
           TokenProvider tokenProvider = GetTokenProvide().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
           string? acessToken = tokenProvider.AccessToken;

           return Task.FromResult(acessToken!);
       }
    }

}
```

I also tried with Delegate Handler

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   
    string? token = _tokenProvider.AccessToken;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token)) request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer ", token);

    HttpResponseMessage? response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

    return response;
}
```

Despite these attempts, I am unable to successfully pass the token to the HttpClient request pipeline. Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your current implementation of `AuthorizationHeaderValueGetter` in `RefitService` uses `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` which can cause issues modify this to be async

```
AuthorizationHeaderValueGetter = async (request, cancellationToken) =>
{
    TokenProvider tokenProvider = await GetTokenProvide();
    string? accessToken = tokenProvider.AccessToken;
    return accessToken;
};
```

Comment: i tried this as well but my token provider always comes back empty or throws an error since i am storing my token in a localStorage

Comment: instead of using ``ProtectedSessionStorage`` just try to store string in session or local storage using 
``sessionStorage.setItem("Token", "jwttoken");``
try like this because with ``ProtectedSessionStorage`` when string length becomes more its retuns as ``null`` even it is stored, I used to face this issue in my projected so i encrpt string and set in session or local storage. so forget about encryption first try to set key directly in session or local storage.

Comment: it's not that returning null ( the session service is a clientSide service and the  refit client is running on the server so i get an exception ), and I also tried sessionStorage before I switched to ProtectedSessionStorage

Comment: My issue is how to get the token stored on the client side and attach it to my request pipeline

Comment: Did you find any solution to address this problem?